# Creating RapidMiner Subprocess to Reduce Repitition

Tags: rapidminer

I'm new to RapidMiner, but am using it to do some text mining and have what is probably a simple question that I can't seem to find an answer to anywhere.

I'm extracting some data from a database into RapidMiner.  From there, I'm filtering the data using an attribute_value_filter to get several subsets from the original data.

After having all of my subsets ready to go, I need to do the exact same operations on each subset (extracting one column of data, creating a document, tokenizing, stemming, removing stop words, etc.).

Is there a way to make a "function", so to speak, in RapidMiner so I don't have to duplicate the exact same set of operations for each subset of data?  I've tried using the subprocess operator, but I can't seem to get an independent output for each independent input.  Perhaps I'm not setting it up right?  I don't have enough reputation points to post images of my processes, but if more details are needed, please let me know.

Any feedback would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Execute Process` operator is a good one to use. This allows for the creation of a library of processes to be used in a modular way.

There's an example at my blog [here](http://rapidminernotes.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/operators-that-deserve-to-be-better.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  This operator is surprisingly under-documented and I can see it being incredibly useful, thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Would you be able to accept the answer to indicate that it works for you?